# I am not sure why undefined appears here while using Async.forEachLimit

Tags: node.js, async.js

```
async.forEachLimit(values,1,(item,valueCallBack)=>{
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      /*beginTransaction*/
      callback(null)
    },
    function(callback){
      /*DB Update*/
      callback(null)
    },
    function(callback){
      /*DB delete*/
      callback(null)
    },
    function(callback){
      /*DB commit*/
      if(error) callback(error,result)
      else callback(null,result)
    }], (error, result) => {
      valueCallBack(error,result)
    })
  }, (error,result) {
    if(error) /* rollback function */
    else res.status(200).send(result); <-- result undefined!!!!!! :(
  })
```

To execute transaction synchronously, I tried to execute one transaction at a time using 'forEachLimit' and 'waterfall', but I couldn't send it with the result appended to the response.
I can't figure out why it is passed undefined at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In the last callback - `/*DB commit*/ callback(null)`, you called `next` with error is null and "result" is undefined. Lets try with  `callback(null, 100)`, you will get `100` instead of `undefined`

Comment: Oh sorry i edit this code, but thank you about your comment

Comment: @이혁진 Again, what is the `result` , is result of `/*DB Update*/` or `/*DB delete*/`, you have put `result` as second param of `callback` function.

Comment: 'result' is result of commit, but i solved this problem using mapLimit, 
Thank you for your effort to give us some advice